# Error installing iptables-persistent

Tags: spi, iptables

I tried to install iptables-persistent without success. I checked the dependent packages and tried to install them manually but it is also not working.

**What I tried:**

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent -y  

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
iptables-persistent is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up netfilter-persistent (1.0.3+deb8u1) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
A dependency job for netfilter-persistent.service failed. See 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript netfilter-persistent, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package netfilter-persistent (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iptables-persistent: iptables-persistent depends on netfilter-persistent (= 1.0.3+deb8u1); however: Package netfilter-persistent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package iptables-persistent (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

netfilter-persistent
 iptables-persistent
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

**And the log:**

```
sudo journalctl -xn      

-- Logs begin at Mon 2017-03-20 22:11:46 WET, end at Mon 2017-03-20 22:17:57 WET. --
Mar 20 22:17:40 prio systemd-modules-load[2274]: Failed to find module 'spi-dev'
Mar 20 22:17:40 prio systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 20 22:17:40 prio systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 20 22:17:40 prio systemd[1]: Dependency failed for netfilter persistent configuration.
-- Subject: Unit netfilter-persistent.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit netfilter-persistent.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 20 22:17:40 prio systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.
Mar 20 22:17:50 prio sudo[2202]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 20 22:17:53 prio kernel: w1_master_driver w1_bus_master1: Family 0 for 00.600000000000.65 is not registered.
Mar 20 22:17:57 prio sudo[2309]: pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Mar 20 22:17:57 prio sudo[2309]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

**About my sistem:**

Raspbian Jessie - release 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I editted the /etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf file and commented out lp, ppdev, and parport_pc with a # in front of each line. I don't intend on printing to anywhere from the Pi, so no harm done I think. I suppose the netfilter tries to load the parallel port and/or centronics ports from ages past when those could act as a sort of network. That is just guessing though. I rebooted and then tried to install iptables-persistent and netfilter-persistent again and they went through.

```
sudo vi /etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf
```

Comment out lp, ppdev, parport_pc so it looks like this:

```
# Parallel printer driver modules loading for cups
# LOAD_LP_MODULE was 'yes' in /etc/default/cups
#lp
#ppdev
#parport_pc
```

Save and exit, reboot:

```
sudo reboot now
```

It should let you run your install again after that.

I found the info at this site here:

OSMC Forums: “failed to start load kernel modules”

  https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules/3163/15

edit: forgot to mention this is on a Raspberry Pi running Jessie. I have Pixel or whatever desktop it comes with on it too.